# OpenMP in Qt on VirtualBox uses only one thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, openmp

I am trying to parallelise part of a C++ program using OpenMP, in QtCreator in Linux on VirtualBox. The host system has 4core cpu. Since my initial attempts at using openmp pragmas didn't seem to work (the code with openmp took almost the same time as that without), I went back to OpenMP wiki and tried to run this simple example.

```
    int main(void)
    {
      #pragma omp parallel
        printf("Hello, world.\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

and the output is just

```
'Hello, world'.
```

I also tried to run this piece of code

```
int main () {
    int thread_number;
    #pragma omp parallel private(thread_number)
    {
        #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            thread_number = omp_get_thread_num();
            cout << "Thread " << thread_number << " says " << i << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
Thread 0 says 0
Thread 0 says 1
Thread 0 says 2
.
.
.
.
Thread 0 says 49
```

So it looks like there is no parallelising happening after all. I have set QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -fopenmp in the .pro file. Is this happening because I am running it from a virtual machine? How do I make multithreading work here? I would really appreciate any suggestions/pointers. Thank you.

Comment: Compiling that code with just `g++ -fopenmp omp.cpp && ./a.out` outputs 4x Hello World for me, so something fishy is going on with your virtualbox, maybe try qemu?

Comment: Multithreading works fine in virtual machines even if they only emulate a single CPU core. It is probably that the `-fopenmp` option doesn't make it to the compiler options or you are using Clang which does not support OpenMP (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that VirtualBox always defaults to a machine with one core.  Go to Settings/System/Processor and increase the number of CPUs to the number of hardware threads (4 in your case or eight if you have hyperthreading).  If you have hyperthreading VirtualBox will warn you that you chose more CPUs than physical CPUs.  Ignore the warning.

I set my CPUs to eight.  When I use OpenMP in GCC on Windows I get eight threads.

Edit: According to [VirtualBox's manaual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor) you should set the number of threads to the number of physical cores not the number of hyper-threads.

> You should not, however, configure virtual machines to use more CPU cores than you have available physically (real cores, no hyperthreads).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS.  The default may be 1 if your virtual machine says it has a single core (this was happening to me).